# Как создать новую метку (tag) средствами XCode?

Tags: xcode, git, git-tag

Есть приложение, его версия 1.0.

Мне нужно создать новую метку, ну скажем с именем версии 1.1. Как это можно легко сделать не выходя из XCode?

Comment: открыть терминал, перейти в каталог с кодом и написать что то в стиле `git tag 1.1`. Но это легковесная метка. А там ещё [два типа](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) как минимум существует.

Это самый легкий и надежный путь.

Comment: А как потом к ней обратится в XCode?

Comment: я не специалист по XCode

Comment: Я просто не очень хорошо владею системой контроля версиями,до этого всё что мне приходилось делать так это коммиты/откат назад/ветки. А воот вообще, как происходит обращение к версии приложения, и коммит на версию? (можно даже с терминала)

Comment: закоммитить на метку - это что то интересное. Метка - это просто отметка коммита. Как на него закоммитить - я не представляю. 

> А воот вообще, как происходит обращение к версии приложения, и коммит на версию? 

обычно делают ветки на версии и коммитят в нужную ветку. Но как это сделано в Вашем случае - я не знаю. Или Эппл в очередной раз что то изобрела?:)

Comment: xCode ни как, это самое убоге существо для работы с гитом, да и скодом тоже. Мало того что он мерджит как косолапоый медведь дак и еще все не правильно. Не пользуйтесь встроенной функция гита в xCode!!! Только консоль, либо SourceThree(ему подобные). По поводу тэгов, это просто метка коммита, на коммит можно чекаутиться, закоммитить на метку по определению не верносе словосочетание.

Comment: попробуйте AppCode http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/ умеет работать с GIT на очень хорошем уровне ну и заточен под разработку для iOS/MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не большой знаток Git, да и в принципе систем контроля версий, но я понял работу меток (тегов) следующим образом (если я не прав, поправьте пожалуйста, мне будет очень интересно узнать):

У меня есть главная ветка, как правило (master), когда приложение подходит к релизу, скажем версия 1.0 доделана до релиза, я пушу все комиты на [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) и создаю тег по этой ветке (master) с помощью программы [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) отмечаю галочкой запушить тег, после чего могу наблюдать, что мой тег успешно запушился в репозиторий (рисунок 1).

[image: Рисунок 1]

А главная ветка (master) будет идти на протяжении всего проекта. А метка останеться не изменяемой. Возможно определение не правильное, но насколько я понял, метка - это как будто вы делаете какой-то проект, и переодически копируете его в папку и архивируете.

Comment: метка - это, грубо говоря, псевдоним хэша коммита с некоторой дополнительной информацией. (метка может быть подписанной, в таком случае можно проверить, что эта метка создана тем, кто об этом написал и ее не модифицировали).